# error when trying to validate json schema

Tags: java, jsonschema, rest-assured, json-schema-validator, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to validate my json response in my rest assured tests and i get the following error in my schema. not sure how to resolve this. any help will be appreciated :) thank you.

error:

```
io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@54c622a7; line: 1, column: 3]
```

schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "status"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "$id": "#/properties/status",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Status Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "PROCESSING"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    }
  }
}
```

method:

```
Assert.assertThat(bookingResponse, matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("book-response-schema.json"));
```

Comment: @mgarcia do you mean the whole schema? i posted it in the question

Comment: My bad, I was trying to ask if you could share the value of `bookingResponse`.

Comment: @mgarcia {status=PROCESSING}

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. `{status=PROCESSING}` is not a valid JSON. To be a valid JSON it should be `{ "status": "PROCESSING" }`.